# Hide the meta prices of the product shopify

Tags: shopify, metadata

In Shopify.

My site hides prices if the user is not logged in. And I have hidden prices everywhere, but I only have to do it in `window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta` (meta prices), which is displayed as a json.

I end up seeing this structure:

```
<script>
window.ShopifyAnalytics = window.ShopifyAnalytics || {};
window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta = window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta || {};
window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.currency = 'USD';
var meta = {"product":{

...

};
for (var attr in meta) {
  window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta[attr] = meta[attr];
}
</script>
```

But how do I hide the prices here?

Comment: Is this `<script>` tag inside a Liquid file (snippet or section) or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if customer == null %}
    <script>
      window.ShopifyAnalytics = window.ShopifyAnalytics || {};
      window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta = window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta || {};

      setTimeout(function()
      {
        delete window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product
      }, 100);
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

paste it on the head tag of your theme.liquid.
the value is not yet evaluated before clicking the > to show the object tree on console.log

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code just inside the  `<head>..</head>` tag in your theme.liquid file.

```
 <head>
 {% if customer == null and template.name == 'product' %}
            <script>
              new function(){
            const me=this;
            const config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false };
            me.init=()=>{    
              me.addObserver(document.querySelector("head"),config,me.callback)
            }
            me.callback = (mutationsList, observer)=> {
                // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
                for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
                    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                     if(window.ShopifyAnalytics && window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta && window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product){
                        for(variant of window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product.variants){
                          if("price" in variant) delete variant.price;
                        }
                        me.stop(observer);
                      }
                    } 
                }        
            };
            me.stop=(observer)=>{observer.disconnect();};
            me.addObserver=(target, config,callback)=>{
                const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
                observer.observe(target, config);
            };
            me.init();
        }
            </script>
            {% endif %}
            </head>
```

It creates an observer that checks if child elements are added to the head.

When a child is added, it then checks if that child is the script that added the `window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta` JS object, by checking if the  `window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta` and `window.ShopifyAnalytics.meta.product` exist.

When it does, the code loops over the product variants and removes the price.

And it only does this when the customer is not logged and on the product page.